# How to call a method which is having dataprovider

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm trying to call a method annotated Test that has dataprovider specified.

```
@Test (dataprovider = test)
public void Login(string a,string b)
```

here String `a` and String `b`
are used to store the value from the data provider. Now i want to call
method `Login` in other class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason why you are invoking the method instead of letting the unit test framework, guessing Testng, invoke it?

Comment: I'd put login method to separate class and call it in any of your tests.

Comment: i have two class login and dashboard. Login class is having method @Test (dataprovider = test) public void Login(string a,string b) . Now i want to access that in dashboard class as without login i can not enter inside dashboard.  if Is there any other way to achieve that, then please tell me as i am new to automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use TestNG. You can call the DataProvider of 1 class from another class. In this case, the `DataProvider` method must be `static`. You also need to include `dataProviderClass` along with `dataProvider`.

Ref:

1. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html
2. https://dzone.com/articles/testng-test-annotation-and